# error Status: 'SyntaxError'. Error code: 0 is coming on jqgrid delete in Internet Explorer (please tell me any iconsistncies with jquery in IE like

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

```
$("#tbl").delGridRow(selr,
{
   msg: "Delete selected rows",
   caption: "Delete Record",
   bSubmit: "Ok",
   bCancel: "Cancel",
   url: '#tbl'             

});
```

i used this to delete data from jqgrid it giving error in IE only on delete ..

Comment: Remove the `,` after `url: '#tbl',`. IE <= 8 doesn't like trailing `,`.

Comment: this is not prob man i tried already my code is working properly in other browser in firefox and chrome problem only in IE with jqgrid delete my developmetn browser is IE wr it work finr

Comment: Welcome to the world of x-browser inconsistencies. Like I said, IE <= 8 doesn't like trailing `,`. All other browsers, and later versions of IE do however. See http://rauschma.github.io/js-feature-matrix/ ("Trailing comma in object literal").

Comment: ya man srry by mistake it happen

Answer (score 2):

Remove `,` in end of the script i.e `url: '#tbl'`

```
$("#tbl").delGridRow(selr,
{
   msg: "Delete selected rows",
   caption: "Delete Record",
   bSubmit: "Ok",
   bCancel: "Cancel",
   url: '#tbl'              

});
```